# Filter Wikipedia geosearch per region

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I saw Wikipedia API (called [MediaWiki GeoData](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData#API)) to search wiki pages around fixed coordinates. An example call is

```
https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gscoord=37.786971|-122.399677
```

I saw also that GeoData, in its *Extra parameters*, has also the concept of *region*, accepting a  [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) region code.

How can I search elements, filtering per this region code?  For example, if I am searching around some coordinates near the border between two regions, am I able to filter only the elements of one region?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Longer answer: submit a feature request at https://phabricator.wikimedia.org , however most geotags don't have region information anyway: http://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/3584

Comment: however, I saw that all the pages about cities or places, has such info in the page. For instance, here in italy, if I visit the page of the [Colosseum](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseo), I can see Country: Italia, City: Rome.  Also small cities has such info, but they are not present in the response.

Comment: That's not structured data and the API doesn't parse it, let alone offer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Longer answer: we currently lack two features which I just filed in the issue tracker for you, i.e.

- [populating the region parameter in GeoData](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T110017): most pages [do not specify the region for GeoData](http://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/3584) but only in their free text (which is useless), the only structured data we have is in Wikidata;
- [adding an option to filter the results by region](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T110016).

For now, you'll have to do everything yourself client-side: figure out the coordinates of each region and filter by those; or search the region in Wikidata statements and then fetch corresponding articles in the language desired. As you are a developer you could also [help import country data in Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Bots) ;-).

(Expanded from MaxSem's answer, hence wiki.)